# Unity3d Cross platform Input GUI Depth

Tags: unity, mobile, cross-platform

I'm creating my GUI controls in Unity 5.3 I have a joystick in which overlays a swipe pad.  Originally all of the controls were working fine.  However, now the touch pad is overlaying the Joystick.

In previous verisons you could focus the window

```
GUI.FocusWindow(0);
```

I've tried reassign the order by making one a child of the other and vise versa yet nothing works.

Does anyone know how to control the Z index of the controls, or make one overlay the other.  I've looked at the GUI depth documentation, but I don't see how I could apply that here.

Does anyone know how to control the depth of cross platform controls in unity?